# Do I need to use celery.result.forget when using a database backend?

Tags: django, celery

I've come across the following warning:

> Backends use resources to store and transmit results. To ensure that resources are released, you must eventually call get() or forget() on EVERY AsyncResult instance returned after calling a task.

I am currently using the [`django-db` backend](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#django-celery-results-using-the-django-orm-cache-as-a-result-backend) and I am wondering about the consequences of not heeding this warning. What resources will not be "released" if I don't `forget` an `AsyncResult`? I'm not worried about cleaning up task results from my database. My primary concern is with the availability of workers being affected.

Answer (score 3):

I've actually never seen that warning.  As long as you're running celery beat, you'll be fine.  Celery has a default periodic task that it sets up for you scheduled to run at 4:00 AM.  That task deletes any expired results in your database if you are using a db-based backend like postgres or mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Celery seems to have a setting for this which is [result_expires](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#std-setting-result_expires). The documentation explains it all:

> ### `result_expires`
>
> Default: Expire after 1 day.
>
> Time (in seconds, or a timedelta object) for when after stored task tombstones will be deleted.

But as @2ps mentioned, celery-beat must be running **for database backends** which as documented tells that:

> A built-in periodic task will delete the results after this time (celery.backend_cleanup), assuming that celery beat is enabled. The task runs daily at 4am.

For other types of backends e.g. AMQP, it seems not necessary as documented:

> #### Note
>
> For the moment this only works with the AMQP, database, cache, Couchbase, and Redis backends.
>
> When using the database backend, celery beat must be running for the results to be expired.